# Stats of already possesed items changed in patch

Tags: diablo-iii

As some people may already now, there is a new patch launching for Diablo 3 soon. Reading through patch notes I came upon a change of an item for one of the classes (specifically monk, but question covers all).

Blizzard made one of the items exceptionally stronger:

> The Fist of Az'Turrasq
>   Exploding Palm's on-death explosion bonus damage has been increased from 75-100% to 250-300%

Links: [Item](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-fist-of-azturrasq), [Patch notes](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19941042/ptr-patchnotes-240-letztes-update-24-november-24-11-2015#erifts)

The question is - I already own one Fist of Az'Turrasq. What happens to this item after patch goes live? Is it rerolled? Or do I have to find another after the patch kicks in, as the one I have doesn't have the stats changed?

Edit: As I kept on reading, I realized one can use Kanai's cube to reroll stats of a legendary item (which The Fist actually is), but will the reroll take in account new stats?

Edit 2: As no-one can actually predict the future and how Blizzard solves this issue, I would like to know how this was dealt with **in the past**. Since asking about unreleased content is considered offtopic, hence this edit.

Comment: With Loot 2.0 the changes to items *weren't* retrospective - items that dropped before the patch still had their old stats. I think subsequent patches have treated item buffs in a similar fashion, so you'd have to find a new version of the item after the patch to get the increased stats.

Comment: @JonK I edited my post with a follow-up question - do you maybe know anything about it?

Comment: the reroll will make a new legendary of the same type, so in theory it should work.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please justify.

Comment: Blizzard *does not retroactively update items you already have*, except for changes to set bonuses as those aren't tied to the item. Legendaries *can be rerolled* to their new stats at the cube as well. I don't have links to support this so I will not make an answer unless I find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [2.4.0 PTR patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19941042/patch-240-ptr-patch-notes-11-11-2015) currently indicate that changes to legendaries, both class-specific and non-class-specific, will not affect existing items except where otherwise specifically noted (and there are a few cases, such as The Tall Man's Finger, where it is).

> Several existing Legendary items have been updated to include a unique Legendary power
>   *Note: Existing items will not be affected by the following changes. Only new versions of the items will roll with the added Legendary power.*

Although things could well change between the PTR and the final release, The Fist of Az'Turrasq is not *presently* labelled as being a retroactive change.

The retroactive changes that *are* marked in 2.4.0 PTR appear to all be changes that don't involve changing the affix description. For example, The Tall Man's Finger describes a change to your Zombie Dogs, but the affix never describes how much health the new ZD has, except that it's more than your old dogs had combined. A change to this health bonus doesn't require any change to the affix description. I'm speculating that the change is retroactive *because* no change to the affix description is required. But don't take that as gospel.

I also wouldn't expect reforging an old item in Kanai's Cube to update it to the new item affixes. When we use the term *rolling*, we're talking about rolling the values inside each affix. Those values can fall within a limited range. The affixes themselves don't change. It's probably best to think of the old item and the new one as completely different items that happen to share a name and appearance. (**EDIT:** I'm getting a lot of people tell me that they think this isn't the case, but nobody seems to have tested it.)

I'm going to [start a new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250644/can-i-claim-bonuses-from-old-and-new-versions-of-a-set-simultaneously) around what the consequences of this might be for set bonuses.

**EDIT: an answerer to my question on sets has indicated that set items are typically updated retroactively to prevent this situation.**

Comment: So this means even rerolling in Kanai's Cube won't work, right? Changed accepted answer to yours, since it gives more source of info and is a better answer in general.

Comment: I doubt reforming with the cube will work. 'Rerolling' means that the random parameters in the affixes are redrawn, not that the affixes themselves are changed. Think of the old item and the new one as different items with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies your answer even more. You might want to add this to the answer's body. So the only thing left for me is farm :)

Comment: The interests g question that this brings up for me is, what if I have an old 6-piece set and I replace 3 pieces of it with the new set? I suspect the answers that you'd have the 2-piece bonus for both the old set and the new set, which could possibly be advantageous in some limited and unepxectedcircumstances. I'm just spit-ballin' here, though; I'd love to see someone verify it. I might start another question.

Comment: Afaik reforging is like a completely new drop of the item. You'll lose any modification and added sockets and it can even change to an ancient version. So I think you should receive the new version of the item. I have no sources to quote though, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Blizzard very rarely does retroactive changes of *legendary* items and as such the Fist will retain it's old values, even if you reroll from Kanai's cube

Comment: You have no proof of this at all.  This is why we don't allow questions about the future of games.

Comment: @Frank proof is tons of items ranging from vanilla to  current ptr, which have remained untouched. Agree with your latter point, answer's more wrt edit 2.

Comment: You're guessing that's what Blizzard is going to be doing for this item.  The answer should specifically be addressing how Blizzard has handled it in the past, not making a guess on how it will handle this in the next patch.

Comment: The 2.4.0 PTR patch notes have a separate section for legendaries that are being given a legendary affix where they had none before This reads, 'Note: Existing items will not be affected by the following changes. Only new versions of the items will roll with the added Legendary power.' The absence of this notice in other sections makes me wonder a bit.