# Can I claim bonuses from old and new versions of a set simultaneously?

Tags: diablo-iii

In [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247650/stats-of-already-possesed-items-changed-in-patch/250625) someone asked how updated items with new affixes worked, and I answered that items with altered affixes are generally distinct, new items, and that existing items are no retroactively updated.

Here's an interesting scenario that may have come up previously because of this but which will almost certainly come up a lot with 2.4.0. Say I have an existing 6-piece set. Then the patch drops, leaving those existing set items intact, but I then go and find 3 pieces of the updated set. What bonuses do I have?

My guess is that I would have the 2-piece bonus from both the old set and the new set concurrently (or, if I have a RORG equipped, the 2-piece and 4-piece bonuses concurrently).

Does anyone have experience from any previous set updates or the 2.4.0 PTR that validates (or falsifies) this hypothesis? For bonus points, are there any circumstances in which you've found this advantageous (eg. double-dipping on similar or identical set bonuses)?

I understand that I'm probably inviting a lot of speculation here; I'm specifically looking for people with existing experience of this situation to comment on it.

Comment: IIRC, set bonuses are updated retroactively. Legendary affixes are not, which is why you can end up with and old/new version of a legendary item, but not a unique (green) set.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure cubing an item before a patch will not keep the old affix after the patch drops, unable to test tho

Comment: It sounds like the cubing problem is moot for set items if they change retroactively, but for regular legs it's another story. I'll update my answer in the other question to qualify my K knowledge on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, sets are always updated retroactively, most likely to prevent scenarios like you desribed them.

[Here is a blue post describing the situation for the patch 2.2](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13901990427#4)

Since it has been the same for patch 2.3 and 2.4 on the PTR (there were even several changes while the 2.4 patch was on the PTR and those changes were also always retroactively) it will most likely be the same for future patches.